# Cell value getting changed when using Apache POI to convert Excel file to Text File

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using below code to convert the numeric value from Excel cell & store in text file.
(apache poi)

```
DataFormatter dfrmt = new DataFormatter();
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
data.append(dfrmt.formatCellValue(cell));
```

with this numeric value are getting converted and store in file, 
but issue is when the cell value starts with zero.

```
Cell Value : 456789   Value in text file : 456789 :: Correct.
Cell Value : 001234   Value in text file : 1234 :: Incorrect.
```

what i want is if value in excel starts with zero it should be same in text file as well

```
Cell Value : 001234   Value in text file : 001234 :: this is required
```

Comment: If the cell is numeric, its value can't be 01234. It might be *formatted* like that but its value is just 1234...

Comment: I am creating an excel file with value as 0012345 in the cell.
and saving the file, not formatting it at all.
then i use above to convert.

Comment: This can be possible if you write all numerics as string format... try this.

Comment: style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("@"))